# Como ejecutar .bat spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch

estoy con un desarollo en spring boot y necesito que al accionar un evento por parte del usuario, se ejecute un archivo bat (solo accede a un directorio, lo limpia y genera un archivo). Estuve intentando con `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(bat)` pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128) ~[na:na]
```

Existe alguna manera de hacer esto? da igual si se ejecuta el archivo o debo llevar el script al proyecto... espero puedan darme una mano, gracias!

Comment: Puede servirte este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application O este https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188037/java-execute-bat-file-when-clicking-button-before-closing-the-java-window

Comment: Gracias @EdgarGc el primer link sirvió para guiarme :)